# Cannot make logo float left of navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I can't make my logo appear to the left of the navigation bar. It just appears in the middle and the navigation menu moves down. Please can you help me to fix it and to understand what I have done wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylecafe.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="contacttop">
    <div id="contacttop2">
        <div id="phoneemail">
            <p><span id="phone">&#9743;</span>&nbsp;012240478624&nbsp;<span id="envelope">&#9993;</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">admin@coffeehouseabz.com</a></p>
        </div>  

        <div id="socialmedia">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/instagram.png" width="16px" height="16px"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/googleplus.png" width="16px" height="16px"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png" width="16px" height="16px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="navwrap">
    <nav>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo"></a>
        <!--<img src="burger.png">-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" id="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="tout.html">Google Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html">Menu&nbsp;&#9660;</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="whatson.html">What's On</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>  

<div id="banner"></div>
<section id="info"></section>
<section id="contactbot">
    <form></form>
    <div id="hours"></div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i');
/*--- css reset ---*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/*--- end css reset ---*/
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#contacttop {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f2e8c1;
}
#contacttop2 {
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #f2e8c1;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#phoneemail {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#phoneemail p {
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#phone, #envelope {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
#socialmedia {
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
}
#socialmedia img {
    display: block;
    margin: 7px 0 7px 14px;
    float: right;
}
#navwrap {
    width: 100%;
    background: #663200;
    height: 90px;
}
nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90px;
}
#logo {
    background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 126px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 7.5px 0;
    float: left;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
    line-height: 90px;
}
nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color:#dddddd;
    font-weight:600;
}
#current {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this what you are looking for. Use the position attribute instead of float. Since you are using background-image, float does not work on background.

So, use position element. It is necessary to use

> position: relative;

for the parent of the element which helps in keeping the element within the bounds of parent.

```css
nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 90px;
    position: relative;
}
#logo {
    background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 126px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 7.5px 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
    line-height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I positioned it now using position absolute. But still, I would like to know the reason the logo would appear in the centre of the div when trying to float it left.

Comment: You cannot use float for the backgrounds, so the float attribute is not applicable. But your previous style has margin: auto, which makes it center.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm pretty confused though. I thought margins were not inherited by the child. Please excuse me as I am a beginner at this.